# When Gentoo emerge world fails, it starts again from the beginning. Why?

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I've been using gentoo for about 10 years. I love the distro. But there is some thing that's been really needling me, and i've never got to the bottom of it, so I thought it might be worth asking in case there's an obvious solution to the problem and I don't know about it.

So this is the problem:

1) I do an emerge world. There's 99 packages to install.

2) 20 packages in, the compilation fails because some dependency is broken or some file is missing or something needs manual intervention. (In this case i needed to do a perl-clean --all).

3) The issue is fixed.

4) I go back to emerge world, expecting it to recognise that i've compiled and installed 19 packages upto the failed packages and supposing it will resume at the failed package with just 80 packages left to compile.

5) IT does not. It ignores the fact that i've compiled 19 packages already and it goes and recompiles them ALL OVER AGAIN. For no apparent reason.

Why does gentoo do this? And is there a fix to this irritating issue. I concede that there may be situations where your fix for an issue may affect one or two packages, but this happens to every package. It wastes entire days. Is there a workaround for this fault?

I've tried doing a --resume, but it compiles something entirely different. --keep-going=y doesn't do exactly what i want either i do want it to stop when there's an error, i just don't want emerge to recompile packages all over again when i emerge world after fixing the issue.

Is anyone else having this issue, or is it just me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you emerge the world set? I think you are probably missing the `-u` flag.

```
$ emerge -u @world
```

Comment: Thanks for reviewing. But the hint to the '-u' flag is the answer.

Comment: Sorry then. +10 for misunderstanding.

Comment: Ahh i was running "emerge world", emerge -u world seems to have sorted it - thanks!